# I need to backup my contacts & information

Tags: contacts, backup, gmail, google-account, restore

I saved my information on gmail then lost my phone. I bought another phone but when I tried to restore my information from the lost phone I remove or delete my all information by mistake. Can you help me to please to restore my information?

Comment: Backup or restore? Backup- save what's in your phone to your Google account. Restore - take what's in your Google account and add it to your phone

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about contacts, you can go to https://contacts.google.com.
Under "More" press "Undo changes" to restore any changes you did to the contacts.